# Is it possible to assert a prop's type in parent component before it reaches children that use the same prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have a component `NotFoundGuard` that only renders children if the given condition is true. Otherwise it renders a generic fallback component to try and avoid some redundancy on something that's pretty common in our codebase.

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to assert to TypeScript that `product` is not `null` by the time it reaches a child component

```
<NotFound if={product != null}>
  <ProductDisplay product={product} />     <- Type 'Product | null' not assignable to type 'Product'
</NotFound>
```

The `NotFound` component looks roughly like this

```
type Props = { if: boolean };

function NotFound(prop: Props): ReactNode {
  if (!props.if) {
    return children;
  }

  return <Fallback />;
}
```

I'd like to avoid asserting with the `!` operator. Updating the component to take a render prop would probably work fine but I'd be more interested in "type magic" even if it's a bit hacky.

My attempt looked like this, which unsurprisingly didn't work.

```
type Props = { if: boolean };

function dummyAssert(cond: boolean): asserts cond is true {}

function NotFound(prop: Props): ReactNode {
  if (!props.if) {
    dummyAssert(props.if);
    return children;
  }

  return <Fallback />;
}
```

Is it possible to get typehints to work correctly in a scenario like this?

```
<NotFound if={product != null}>
  <ProductDisplay product={product} /> // No type error here about potential null prop
</NotFound>
```

Comment: A conditional statement (if else, tertiary) with a branch where `product` is not `null`... already asserts to Typescript that `product` is not `null`. You're making this far more difficult than it is.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would give up on `<NotFound />` entirely and simplify down to:

```
{
  product === null ? <Fallback /> : <ProductDisplay product={product} />
}
```

---

But let's leave that aside — and keep `<NotFound />` (pretend it had more business logic, or that we didn't want to expose/repeat this logic into components containing `<NotFound />`) — the correct solution, IMHO, ***is*** the non-null assertion operator:

```
<NotFound if={product !== null}>
  <ProductDisplay product={product!} />
</NotFound>
```

Why?

The crux of the matter is that TS doesn't know what `if` does, type-wise.
So we have to inform it, in the parent component, about our custom logic (contained in `if` directive) in a way that TS understands. This means the alternative to using the non-null operator is

```
<NotFound if={product !== null}>
  {
    product !== null && <ProductDisplay product={product} />
  }
</NotFound>
```

which, in my opinion, is worse (we have to repeat the contents of `if` inside the JSX markup).

---

Now let's take a step back and ask ourselves: *"What is the non-null assertion operator? Why does it exist and when should it be used?"*
It is for cases where TS is not able to correctly determine the nullability of an expression. In this case, we know with absolute certainty that `product` cannot be be passed as `null` to `<ProductDisplay />`, but TS is not able to determine that. ***<sup>1</sup>***

So the non-null assertion operator is not a mistake/hack/sweep-under-the-rug here, but the correct solution. It was developed precisely for cases like ours and we ***should*** be using it. ***<sup>2</sup>***

In your own words, it's the *"type magic"* you've been looking for.

---

***<sup>1</sup>*** - if you're curious about why is TS not able to pick up on what the `if` directive does, it's because TS has no insight into how React interprets JSX to create DOM elements and what are the relations between those DOM elements, once created. In short, TS doesn't know what `children` stands for in the context of a React component.
***<sup>2</sup>*** - the wrong usage of the non-null operator would be to suppress a valid warning (in this example, if the possibility of passing `product` as `null` to `<ProductDisplay />` actually existed).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on tao's answer, it is still possible to enjoy the best of both worlds by passing the children conditionally on the parent element, rather than inside the component (as a child). That way, the parent element processes the type checking and notifies if there are any conflicts, *without* explicitly non-null asserting(!) the prop. For this solution to work, `NotFoundGuard` component would need to be refactored:

```js
type Props = { children?: React.ReactNode };

function NotFoundGuard(props: Props): React.ReactNode {
    if (props.children) {
        return props.children;
    }

    return <Fallback />;
}
```

### Usage:

```js
<NotFoundGuard>
    {product !== null && <ProductDisplay product={product} />}
</NotFoundGuard>
```

Comment: Good refactoring idea. It also increases flexibility, as you can group more optional components into a single `<NotFoundGuard />`, which wasn't as easy with `if`. Quite neat.

Answer (score -1):

In TypeScript, you can achieve more accurate type checking by using generics along with conditional types.

```
type Props<T> = { if: T extends null ? false : true; children: React.ReactNode }

function NotFound<T>(props: Props<T>): React.ReactNode {
  if (!props.if) {
    return props.children
  }

  return <Fallback />
}
```

Comment: Now, when you use the NotFound component, TypeScript will correctly infer the type based on the condition:

Comment: <NotFound if={product !== null}>
  <ProductDisplay product={product} /> {/* No type error here */}
</NotFound>

<NotFound if={product === null}>
  <ProductDisplay product={product} /> {/* Type error: Property 'product' does not exist on type 'null' */}
</NotFound>

Comment: Tested [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQFAwCeYWcACsQCYCu+cAvHAG8acEXGDsAXHFQwowAHYBzGgF8adRszYQwqADwAVAHx9BYglINwsADxhZ57dPM4AbV3AD8cAslepmKVlOLABuOFwAC2BXdkp5KWw8GAA6JPwAOQh2ZjUaAk55fGAIeTgsmAAxCEL2QyMACjBiXSltXXqASkSqVPSYLJzBYThKGE4oMoBCZp1UFOACLzhZ3RSomLiHOCk9dmAANyNfdwAjPABrPQB6faPVdVxSmVYObhgAEWBUMFdkelMDQEKzePBUUmBsy4+DaoPgKk6fBMDRGe0ORgEUPeC3YKhudyMNE6j2e8AMWBe-AaiN4JiEIie8heAG0sfgADTSLAwbTQmAAXVM-RSnACAGUYMh7Hpee84AAfOAudyNZWuYkiMYTMoo0RwPQVaq1cy8TFwuBTXj8NUqQl6kQyuFfH5-AFsmCm90qODXO2iG6GmqOP3EtRAA). Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -1):

TypeScript supports conditional types and assertion functions for this purpose you can achieve type hinting and assert the prop type in the parent component before it reaches the children.

```
type Props<T> = { if: boolean; children: React.ReactElement<T> };

function dummyAssert<T>(cond: T): asserts cond is Exclude<T, null> {
  if (cond === null) {
    throw new Error("Assertion failed: value is null");
       }
    }

       function NotFound<T>(props: Props<T>): React.ReactNode {
             if (!props.if) {
                       return props.children;
                            }

        dummyAssert(props.children.props);
         return <Fallback />;
       }
```

The `dummyAssert` function takes a generic type `T` and asserts that it is not `null`. The Props type is also generic which is allowing you to pass the specific type of the child component to the `NotFound` component.

```
<NotFound<Product> if={product != null}>
    <ProductDisplay product={product} /> 
</NotFound>
```

Comment: I tested this in TS playground and it doesn't seem to work. Unfortunately, the link is too long to share. Can you provide a working example?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the working example for your reference:-

```
import React from 'react';

type Props<T> = { if: boolean; children: React.ReactElement<T> };

function dummyAssert<T>(cond: T): asserts cond is Exclude<T, null> {
  if (cond === null) {
    throw new Error("Assertion failed: value is null");
  }
}

function NotFound<T>(props: Props<T>): React.ReactNode {
  if (!props.if) {
    return props.children;
  }

  dummyAssert(props.children.props);
  // Add your fallback Component
  return <div>Fallback Component</div>;
}

// Working Example
type Product = {
  // Define your product type here
  name: string;
  price: number;
};

const product: Product | null = /* your product data */ null;

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <NotFound<Product> if={product != null}>
      <div>{product?.name}</div>
      <div>{product?.price}</div>
    </NotFound>
  );
};

export default App;
```